error: Two different url values supplied: `<my_domain>` (from token), `https://sentry.io`
Getting this error when starting project after adding sentryWebpackPlugin (according to this doc https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/sourcemaps/uploading/webpack/)
I already have Sentry in the project and just want to get source map
Checked the token, DSN - they are from the same project.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

you can also create an issue here with example config from your SDK init and webpack config, then we can address
https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-javascript
